# How can I hide a popup window in an AutoIt script?

Tags: windows, autoit

I install a file using the code below;

```
Run("file.exe", "", @SW_HIDE)
WinWait("install", "")
WinSetState("install", "", @SW_HIDE)
Sleep(2000)
ControlSend('install', '', '', 'E-mail')
ControlSend('install', '', '', '{ENTER}')
WinWait("install", "")
WinSetState("install", "", @SW_HIDE)
```

It can hide the console window, but after a few seconds...

A system popup shows another installation window for a bit and then hides, showing installation progress.

I want to know how to hide this window as well as the console window.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to run an application with autoit on a hidden desktop in windows such that no windows will ever be visible to the user. It is even possible to interact with this application and its windows via the built-in send()/click()/etc... autoit functions.

[Here](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/183518-method-for-interaction-with-hidden-windows/) is a link to the autoit code to do this on the autoit forums

Here is the code in case the link dies:

**hiddenDesktopInteract.au3:**

```
#Region ;**** Directives created by AutoIt3Wrapper_GUI ****
#AutoIt3Wrapper_UseUpx=y
#EndRegion ;**** Directives created by AutoIt3Wrapper_GUI ****
#include <WinAPI.au3>
#include <WinAPIEx.au3>
#include <GDIPlus.au3>

;1st command line param that will launch seperate instance
Const $hdiParam = 'hiddenDesktopInteract'

;######DO NOT PUT ANY OTHER CODE ABOVE THIS THAT CALLS A 2ND INSTANCE OF THE SCRIPT OR ELSE YOU MAY END UP CALLING INFINITE INSTANCES AND CRASHING WINDOWS!!!!!!
;seperate process for hidden desktop interaction
;1st param should be 'hiddenDesktopInteract' and 2nd param is name of func to call for interaction code
;ex: "autoit.exe script.au3 hiddenDesktopInteract interactionfunc" or "compiledscript.exe hiddenDesktopInteract interactionfunc"
if $CmdLine[0] = 2 AND $CmdLine[1] = $hdiParam Then EXIT Call($CmdLine[2])

;credit to Decipher in thread https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/152515-start-a-process-hidden/#comment-1095173 for code for running process on a hidden desktop
Func _hiddenDesktopInteract_run($sProgram, $sInteractionFunc, $sCommand = '')
    ;if the interaction function does not exist then don't do anything
    If Not IsFunc(Execute($sInteractionFunc)) Then
        ConsoleWrite('error: interaction function "' & $sInteractionFunc & '" for "' & $sProgram & '" does not exist' & @CRLF)
        Return
    EndIf

    ;create structs
    Local $tStartupInfo = DllStructCreate($tagStartupInfo)
    DllStructSetData($tStartupInfo, "Size", DllStructGetSize($tStartupInfo))
    Local $tProcessInfo_targetApp = DllStructCreate($tagPROCESS_INFORMATION)
    Local $tProcessInfo_interactionScript = DllStructCreate($tagPROCESS_INFORMATION)

    ; Create Desktop
    Local $hDesktop = _WinAPI_CreateDesktop('AutoItHidden', BitOR($DESKTOP_CREATEWINDOW, $DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP))
    If Not $hDesktop Then
        MsgBox(0, 'Error', 'Unable to create desktop.')
        Exit
    EndIf

    ; Prep Process Info
    Local $nSuccess = DllStructSetData($tStartupInfo, "Desktop", _WinAPI_CreateString("AutoItHidden"))

    ;run target program on hidden desktop and get PID
    _WinAPI_CreateProcess('', '"' & $sProgram & '"' & ($sCommand ? ' ' & $sCommand : ''), 0, 0, 0, 0x00000200, 0, 0, DllStructGetPtr($tStartupInfo), DllStructGetPtr($tProcessInfo_targetApp))
    Local $aPID_targetApp = DllStructGetData($tProcessInfo_targetApp, 'ProcessID')
    ConsoleWrite('!>target app PID:' & $aPID_targetApp & @CRLF)

    ;run instance of this script on hidden desktop to interact with target program
    Local $sParams = '"' & @ScriptFullPath & '" ' & $hdiParam & ' ' & $sInteractionFunc
    Switch @Compiled
        case True
            Local $sAppName = @ScriptFullPath
            Local $sCommandLine = $sParams
        case False
            Local $sAppName = @AutoItExe
            Local $sCommandLine = '"' & @AutoItExe & '" ' & $sParams
    EndSwitch
    _WinAPI_CreateProcess('', $sCommandLine, 0, 0, 0, 0x00000200, 0, 0, DllStructGetPtr($tStartupInfo), DllStructGetPtr($tProcessInfo_interactionScript))

    ;and get PID of interaction instance so we can wait until it is finished
    Local $iPID_interactionScript = DllStructGetData($tProcessInfo_interactionScript, 'ProcessID')
    ConsoleWrite('!>Interaction Script PID: ' & $iPID_interactionScript & @CRLF)

    ;wait until interaction script instance is finished and get exit code (which is return value from interaction function)
    ProcessWaitClose($iPID_interactionScript)
    Local $exitcode_interactionScript = @extended
    ConsoleWrite("!>Interaction Script Exit Code: " & $exitcode_interactionScript & @CRLF)
    Local $sOutput = StdoutRead($iPID_interactionScript)
    ConsoleWrite("!>Interaction Script Stdout: " & $sOutput & @CRLF)

    ;close hidden desktop
    Local $aRet = DllCall("User32.dll", "int", "CloseDesktop", "handle", $hDesktop)
    ConsoleWrite("!>Close Desktop: " & $aRet[0] & @CRLF) ; Non-Zero is successfull!

    Return $exitcode_interactionScript
EndFunc

Func _hiddenDesktopInteract_cap($title, $imgfile, $Left = 0, $Top = 0, $Right = -1, $Bottom = -1)
    _GDIPlus_Startup()
    $hWnd = WinGetHandle($title)
    $iWidth = _WinAPI_GetWindowWidth($hWnd)
    $iHeight = _WinAPI_GetWindowHeight($hWnd)
    $hDDC = _WinAPI_GetDC($hWnd)
    $hCDC = _WinAPI_CreateCompatibleDC($hDDC)
    $hBMP = _WinAPI_CreateCompatibleBitmap($hDDC, $iWidth, $iHeight)
    _WinAPI_SelectObject($hCDC, $hBMP)
    DllCall("User32.dll", "int", "PrintWindow", "hwnd", $hWnd, "hwnd", $hCDC, "int", 0)
    _WinAPI_ReleaseDC($hWnd, $hDDC)
    _WinAPI_DeleteDC($hCDC)
    $hBMPclone = _GDIPlus_BitmapCreateFromHBITMAP($hBMP)
    if $Right = -1 then
        $iX = _GDIPlus_ImageGetWidth($hBMPclone) - $Left
    Else
        $iX = $Right - $Left
    EndIf
    if $Bottom = -1 then
        $iY = _GDIPlus_ImageGetHeight($hBMPclone) - $Top
    Else
        $iY = $Bottom - $Top
    EndIf
    ;convert from 32bit bitmap to 24bit bitmap b/c 32bit bitmap cannot display correctly in autoit GUI for some reason
    $hClone = _GDIPlus_BitmapCloneArea($hBMPclone, $Left, $Top, $iX, $iY, $GDIP_PXF24RGB)
    _GDIPlus_ImageSaveToFile($hClone, $imgfile)
    _WinAPI_DeleteObject($hBMP)
    _WinAPI_DeleteObject($hBMPclone)
    _WinAPI_DeleteObject($hClone)
    _GDIPlus_Shutdown()
EndFunc
```

The example script demonstrates running a hidden instance of notepad and cmd.exe and interacting with it via controlclick() and controlsend() and then capturing a screencap of the window before closing it.

**hiddenDesktopInteract_EXAMPLES.au3:**

```
#include "hiddenDesktopInteract.au3"

;test function for interacting with notepad app on hidden desktop
func notepadtest()
    opt('winwaitdelay', 0)  ;to make it run a little bit faster
    WinWait('[CLASS:Notepad]')
    $hwin = WinGetHandle('[CLASS:Notepad]')
    ControlSend($hwin, '', '[CLASS:Edit; INSTANCE:1]', 'hello{ENTER}')
    WinMenuSelectItem($hwin, '', '&Edit', 'Time/&Date')
    _hiddenDesktopInteract_cap($hwin, @DesktopDir & '\notepad_cap.jpg')
    ControlSend($hwin, '', '[CLASS:Edit; INSTANCE:1]', '^a')
    ControlSend($hwin, '', '[CLASS:Edit; INSTANCE:1]', '{DELETE}')
    WinClose($hwin)
EndFunc

;test function for interacting with cmd.exe on hidden desktop
func cmdtest()
    opt('winwaitdelay', 0)  ;to make it run a little bit faster
    WinWait('[CLASS:ConsoleWindowClass]')
    $hwin = WinGetHandle('[CLASS:ConsoleWindowClass]')
    ControlSend($hwin, '', '', 'dir{ENTER}')
    sleep(500)
    _hiddenDesktopInteract_cap($hwin, @DesktopDir & '\cmd_cap.jpg')
    ControlSend($hwin, '', '', 'exit{ENTER}')
EndFunc

_hiddenDesktopInteract_run("notepad.exe", 'notepadtest')
_hiddenDesktopInteract_run("cmd.exe", 'cmdtest')
```

This is pretty much just a copy-paste from the autoit forum post but I don't think doing that is a problem because I am the author of that post.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide any window using [WinSetState](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinSetState.htm), but naturally you won't be able to interact with the controls of this window any longer.

```
; wait for the window to appear
Local $hWnd = WinWait("[CLASS:TheAppToHide]")

; hide the window using the handle returned from WinWait
WinSetState($hWnd, "", @SW_HIDE)
```

Comment: you are right but when i send
ControlSend('install', '', '', '{ENTER}')
the app open a new window and i want to hide it

Comment: Then you should use WinWait on that popup window and hide it with WinSetState as I wrote. Or do you mean that it continuously creates popup windows?

Comment: i use WinWait on that popup window but it open for a moment and then hide